# How to use the Fortran compiler in Intel Parallel Studio XE with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, fortran, intel-fortran

I am trying to debug a Fortran code. I have installed Intel Parallel Studio XE which includes the iFort compiler and Microsoft Visual Studio. During the installation of Intel Parallel Studio XE, it showed a message saying it's now integrated with Visual Studio 2019 but when I try to create a new project in Visual Studio, it does not show an option for Intel Fortran Compiler, so I cannot create a Fortran project.
Any ideas on how to use the Intel Fortran compiler with Visual Studio?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome. You can of course ask here and you are likely to get a good answer but you it is also good to know that Intel has good support forums where there is a lot of information and the feedback to users' questions is usually good and quick. https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler

Comment: Thanks a lot for directing me to the Intel Developer forum, I found the solution which I have posted below as it might be helpful for others as well.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution... posting here so that it can help others who might stumble upon the same problem. You need to install the Desktop development with C++ workload in Visual Studio. Refer to the links below:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler/topic/843126

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-parallel-studio-xe-compilers-required-microsoft-visual-studio